# gdb check macro value not work for android

Tags: android, gdb

When I use gdb debug on android native application, I always can not get macro value with below command:

```
(gdb) info macro ERROR_IO
The symbol `ERROR_IO' has no definition as a C/C++ preprocessor macro
at <user-defined>:-1
```

The definition of ERROR_IO in source code as below:

```
namespace android {

enum {
    MEDIA_ERROR_BASE        = -1000,

    ERROR_ALREADY_CONNECTED = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE,
    ERROR_NOT_CONNECTED     = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE - 1,
    ERROR_UNKNOWN_HOST      = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE - 2,
    ERROR_CANNOT_CONNECT    = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE - 3,
    ERROR_IO                = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE - 4,
    ERROR_CONNECTION_LOST   = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE - 5,
```

That means the value should be -1004. but command works fine:

```
(gdb) p ERROR_IO+0
$5 = -1004
```

Does that means definition not correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ERROR_IO` is not a macro, it is an enum constant.  So, `info macro` won't show it.

FYI, you can get the same effect as `+0' using the`/d` modifier:

```
(gdb) p/d ERROR_IO
```